# How to use android renderscript while building with bazel

Tags: android, bazel, renderscript, android-renderscript

I've been building a project with bazel and want to use renderscript features, but I can't find a way to link it to my project.

I tried to make a dependency on android support v8 renderscript but that does not seem to exist. I tried using maven to download it but it does not seem to exist on maven either. I can find renderscript in my sdk but its located in build-tools in some obscure path, and I don't know how to include it from there. All current documentation only shows how to use gradle and renderscript. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hi, were you able to implement it? I am stuck at the same thing.